# Textview in tableviewcell getting overwritten

Tags: ios7, uitableview, uitextview

I have a tableview in which i want to populate a few tweets. I have a textview using which I am populating the contents of the tweet in each tableview cell. However this textview is being over written. Can someone have a look at my code below and let me know if I have made any mistake?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FeedCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *tweet = tweetArray[indexPath.row];

    NSString *tweetText = tweet[@"text"];

    CGSize stringSize = [tweetText sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    textV=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 290, stringSize.height+5)];

    textV.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];

    textV.text = tweetText;

    textV.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    textV.editable = NO;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:textV];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You 've got few tweets so instead of dequing (i.e making reuse of cell) , create new cell. Use the following code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];        
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }
NSDictionary *tweet = tweetArray[indexPath.row];

NSString *tweetText = tweet[@"text"];

CGSize stringSize = [tweetText sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15]     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 9999) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

textV=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 290, stringSize.height+5)];

textV.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];

textV.text = tweetText;

textV.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; textV.editable = NO;

[cell.contentView addSubview:textV];

        return cell;
```

}

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I have 20 tweets would it be ok to create a new cell instead of dequeuing it?

Comment: yes that's ok, you better reuse the cell not in the view instead of creating. Are you using the storyboard here?